# iCal Format - storing the event creator

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545

I am currently programming a scheduling application which loosely based on iCalendar standard. Does anyone knows in which property can I store the event creator's information? By browsing through the iCalendar RFC 2445, I find this property: [Organizer](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/organizer.html). can I store the event creator's information in the property even if he/she is the only person involved in the event? or there is already a field to store the event creator's information???!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some notes from the rfc2445

Conformance: This property MUST be specified in an iCalendar object
   that specifies a group scheduled calendar entity. This property MUST
   be specified in an iCalendar object that specifies the publication of
   a calendar user's busy time. This property **MUST NOT be specified** in
   an iCalendar object that specifies only a time zone definition or
   that **defines calendar entities that are not group scheduled entities,
   but are entities only on a single user's calendar**.

Answer (score 7):

`ORGANIZER;CN="Sally Example":mailto:sally@example.com`

Looks like the answer

Comment: i know, but is it appropriate?

Comment: i mean... if I am the only one involved in the event, is it appropriate to use this property???

Answer (score 1):

I am researching a similar application, concerned with event tracking and handling, and came to the same conclusions as Jeffrey04.

Specifically, to represent warning or alarm, it would seem appropriate to use the VJOURNAL component, as the event is in the past, and maybe continues through the present, but is certainly not a meeting. VJOURNAL also does not occupy space on the calendar.
IMHO the best field for representing the originator is **X-WR-RELCALID**, which is not RFC5545, but seems to fit the idea of a creator UID. I will link this to a vCard UID.

I cannot understand why the idea of an event creator was unimportant for the writers of iCal specs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer simonpa71. Could you explain why do you htink X-WR-RELCALID is the best field for the job? Also- did you find any fields in RFC5545 good for this?

Comment: hi @jedrus07, conclusions partly based on [MS use of the field] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179588%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). Another option in RFC5545 is the CONTACT property. By using the CONTACT;ALTREP you can reference an URI like LDAP or vcard.