# what is the purpose/usage for the EventKit EKEvent "organizer" property?

Tags: iphone, ios, eventkit

what is the purpose/usage for the EventKit EKEvent "organizer" property?

The doco says "The organizer associated with the event" however I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Does this post help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80101/ical-format-organizer-property; specifically: http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/organizer.html

Comment: yes - the 2nd link helped out - do you to suggest it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organizer property refers to the "organizer of the event (or calendar) event".  If you start with this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) page, you'll soon find [RFC2446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446) to read!; search here the stand-out quote is:

> The CU (Calender User) who initiates an exchange takes on the role of "Organizer"