# ORGANIZER attribute on ics calendar invite

Tags: php, icalendar

I am building a website where the user clicks a link and it downloads an calendar invite/ics file. The file is generated using PHP. I am adding the ORGANIZER attribute:

```
$ics_props = array(
  'BEGIN:VCALENDAR',
  'VERSION:2.0',
  'PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN',
  'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN',
  'BEGIN:VEVENT',
  'ORGANIZER:MAILTO:info@mydomain.com'
);
```

And when the file is downloaded I can see that the attribute is there:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:info@mydomain.com
```

However, when I add the invite to Outlook, the organizer is shown as myself. I need it to show as the email that I have specified. Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do any of the restrictions mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/99838/10955263 apply for the type of event you are creating there?

Comment: So it looks like it doesn't display because there is only a single attendee for the appointment? Makes sense. Thank you.